# `Send` is not implemented when attempting Inversion of Control in Rust

Tags: rust, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, rust-tonic

## Summary

When trying to have a tonic server class depend on a trait, I get a compile-time issue about the trait not implementing Send or Sync. My intent is to have the server class depend on the trait rather than the concrete implementation of that trait (inversion of control).

## Setup

I have a `RegistrationServiceApi` trait that is implemented by a `RegistrationServiceImpl`

```rust
pub trait RegistrationServiceApi {
    fn register_user(&self, request: RegisterUserRequest) -> RegisterUserResponse;
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct RegistrationServiceImpl {}

impl RegistrationServiceApi for RegistrationServiceImpl {
    fn register_user(&self, request: RegisterUserRequest) -> RegisterUserResponse {
        ...
    }
}
```

I also have a `RegistrationServiceServerImpl` that is implementing a `RegistrationService` gRPC class generated by prost (annotated with `#[tonic::async_trait]`) that depends on the`RegistrationServiceApi`.

```rust
pub struct RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
    registration_service: Arc<dyn RegistrationServiceApi>,
}

impl RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
    pub fn new(registration_service: Arc<RegistrationServiceImpl>) -> Self {
        RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
            registration_service,
        }
    }
}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl RegistrationService for RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
    async fn register_user(
        &self,
        request: Request<RegisterUserRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<RegisterUserResponse>, Status> {
        let req = request.into_inner();
        Ok(Response::new(self.registration_service.register_user(req)))
    }
}
```

## Problem

The setup above yields the following compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> project/src/registration_service_server.rs:21:6
    |
21  | impl RegistrationService for RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static)`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `Arc<(dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static)>`
note: required because it appears within the type `RegistrationServiceServerImpl`
   --> project/src/registration_service_server.rs:8:12
    |
8   | pub struct RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `RegistrationService`
   --> 
    |
194 |     pub trait RegistrationService: Send + Sync + 'static {
    |                                           ^^^^ required by this bound in `RegistrationService`
```

## Attempts

I've tried replacing the dependency on the trait with a dependency on the implementation class:

```rust
pub struct RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
    registration_service: Arc<RegistrationServiceImpl>,
}
```

This works but violates inversion of control.

I've also tried having the `RegistrationServiceApi` extend `Send` and `Sync`, but that doesn't resolve the issue. In hindsight, that makes sense given the error was about `dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static`.

Comment: Making the trait having `Send` and `Sync` as supertraits should work. Can you show the code?

Comment: You can also try changing `registration_service: Arc<dyn RegistrationServiceApi>` to `registration_service: Arc<dyn RegistrationServiceApi + Send + Sync>`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added both `Send` and `Sync` as super traits:
```
`(dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static)` doesn't implement `Debug`
the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `(dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static)`
the following other types implement trait `Debug`:
```

Now, I see an exception about the debug trait: `the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `(dyn RegistrationServiceApi + 'static)``

Comment: How is `Debug` related here?

Comment: It was required because the `RegistrationServiceServerImpl` had the derive debug macro. My issue is resolved by adding both send and sync as supertypes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, thanks to [Chayim Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884305/chayim-friedman) was to add both `Sync` and `Send` as supertraits.

```rust
pub trait RegistrationServiceApi: Send + Sync {
    fn register_user(&self, request: RegisterUserRequest) -> RegisterUserResponse;
}

pub struct RegistrationServiceServerImpl {
    registration_service: Arc<dyn RegistrationServiceApi>,
}
```